# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Apples'. No child element expected at

Tags: xml, exception, xslt, saxparseexception

I have an xml file generated using xslt script which I am trying to upload to a UI but when I try to do so I get the below exception for one of the tags,
**org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Apples'. No child element is expected at this point**

Below is the block from xsl script that's creating trouble,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:ns2="http://www.google.com/fruits"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<ns2:FruitCatalog>

<xsl:variable name="schemaVersion" select="'26.0'"/>

<!-- The variable schemaVersion can be used for further processing.  -->
<xsl:attribute name="schemaVersion"><xsl:value-of select="$schemaVersion"/></xsl:attribute>

<Apples>
<xsl:for-each select="/ns2:FruitCatalog/Apples/Apple">
<Apple>
<xsl:attribute name="color"><xsl:value-of select="./@color"/></xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="type"><xsl:value-of select="./@type"/></xsl:attribute>
<Price><xsl:value-of select="./Price"/></Price>
</Apple>
</xsl:for-each>
</Apples>

</ns2:FruitCatalog>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xml that I am converting using the above xsl format is as below,

```html
<Apples>
        <Apple color="green" type="A">
            <Price>Dollar_1</Price>
        </Apple>
        <Apple color="yellow" type="B">
            <Price>Dollar_1</Price>
        </Apple>
        <Apple color="red" type="C">
            <Price>Dollar_1</Price>
        </Apple>
        <Apple color="purple" type="D">
            <Price>Dollar_2</Price>
        </Apple>
        <Apple color="orange" type="E">
            <Price>Dollar_2</Price>
        </Apple>
        <Apple color="blue" type="F">
            <Price>Dollar_2</Price>
        </Apple>
        <Apple color="white" type="G">
            <Price>Dollar_2</Price>
        </Apple>
        <Apple color="black" type="H">
            <Price>Dollar_3</Price>
        </Apple>
        <Apple color="pink" type="I">
            <Price>Dollar_3</Price>
        </Apple>
        <Apple color="brown" type="J">
            <Price>Dollar_3</Price>
        </Apple>
        <Apple color="magenta" type="K">
            <Price>Dollar_3</Price>
        </Apple>
    </Apples>
```

Comment: Invalid means you validate against a schema so we need to see a minimal but complete schema and a minimal but complete instance document.

Comment: I didn't get you @MartinHonnen

Comment: The error message (which tool or software exactly do you use?) suggests there is some schema based validation happening based on which you then get a validation error (invalid content). To allow anyone here to tell why you get that validation error, we need to see minimal but complete samples of both the use XML instance as well of the used XSD schema document.

Comment: I have updated the required details that might help you understand the issue better. Please ignore the absurd tag names and values as I have replaced the original ones to avoid sharing important data. Be rest assured that the schema is intact

Comment: No you haven’t. You were asked for the schema. Provide it.